# When in 1885 did Stafford Northcote cease to be Commons leader of the Conservatives?

Tags: political-history, united-kingdom

Northcote was leader in the Commons until 1885. Wikipedia says:

> On Benjamin Disraeli's elevation to the House of Lords as Earl of Beaconsfield in 1876, Northcote became Leader of the Conservatives in the Commons[...]
>
> His temper as leader was, however, too gentle to satisfy the more ardent spirits among his own followers. Party cabals (in which Lord Randolph Churchill took a leading part) led to Northcote's elevation to the Lords in 1885, when Lord Salisbury [Con. leader in the lords] became prime minister.

This is odd, because the Conservatives defeated the Liberal government in the 1885 general election, and formed a government. Presumably Northcote had some role in the electioneering that gained them this victory. Did they oust Northcote before or after the election?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Lord Salisbury became prime minister on 23 June 1885, while Northcote was elevated to the peerage on 3 July 1885 (i.e., 10 days later). I think 'oust' is probably the wrong term, since he wasn't removed from office nor was he excluded from the party. He was just bumped "upstairs" to allow a stronger character to become the party leader in the commons.

Comment: Apparently right after elections: A. Lang, *Life, Letters, and Diaries of Sir Stafford Northcote, First Earl of Iddesleigh*, Edinburgh & London: Blackwood 1891, pp. 355-358: "On July 6, Sir Stafford took his seat in the House of Lords as Earl of Iddesleigh [...] *June 15* [...] Salisbury's present idea is, that I should take the post of First Lord of the Treasury, and lead the Commons, with F. Stanley for my Chancellor of the Exchequer. I have offered either to do this or go to the Upper House, taking the India Office. [...] This has apparently been my last night in the House of Commons [...]"

Comment: @KillingTime Yes Minister said that giving an MP a peerage is *approbation, elevation, and castration*. Admittedly that was written 100 years after Northcote. He may have genuinely not wanted to be prime minister or commons leader and seen a peerage as a greater honour, which in fact it is in aristocratic terms. Or he may have wished to stay on but agreed to go quietly with a consolation prize. Interesting to know which.

Comment: Oh, I see he says in his diary he *offered* to go to the Lords, so perhaps the first one is right. Surprising given he'd just won a general election.

Comment: @NeMo: What general election was that? The general election in [1880](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1880_United_Kingdom_general_election) was a Liberal majority; [that in 1885](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1885_United_Kingdom_general_election) was still 5 months in the future; and the Conservative Party that won in [1886](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1886_United_Kingdom_general_election) was [led solely by Marquess of Salisbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_of_the_Conservative_Party_(UK)) after Northcote had stepped to the Lords.

Answer (score 6):

From [The London Gazette, Issue 25486 Page 3060, published 3 July 1885](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/25486/page/3060):

> #### Whitehall, July 2, 1885.

> The Queen has been pleased to direct Letters Patent to be passed under the Great Seal, granting the dignities of a Viscount and an Earl of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland unto the Right Honourable Sir Stafford Henry Northcote, [Bart.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baronet), [G.C.B.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Knights_Grand_Cross_of_the_Order_of_the_Bath), and the heirs male of his body lawfully begotten, by the names, styles, and titles of Viscount Saint Cyres, of Newton Saint Cyres, in the county of Devon, and Earl of Iddesleigh, in the said county.

> [image]

Likewise in the Gazette some days earlier, [Issue 25484 page 2919 published 26 June, 1885](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/25484/page/2919):

> At the Court at Windsor the 24th day of June, 1885
> PRESENT.
> The QUEEN's Most Excellent Majesty in Council.
> This day the Right Honourable Sir Stafford Henry Northcote, Baronet, took the oaths of First Lord of Her Majesty's Treasury.

Mysteriously (to me at least) I can find no introduction of Earl Iddesleigh to the House of Lords in its [July, 1885, Hansard](https://hansard.parliament.uk/lords/1885-07-01) despite the introduction of several other new peers that month, including:

- [9 July 1885](https://hansard.parliament.uk/lords/1885-07-09/debates/3ef0aa0c-403c-48a8-b7e8-c6fca524fa57/NewPeer):

  - Baron Rothschild of Tring in the county of Hertford
- [13 July 1885](https://hansard.parliament.uk/lords/1885-07-13/debates/d680cbf0-d3a9-4678-9ac8-262df213a7e0/NewPeers):

  - Baron Powerscourt, of Powerscourt in the county of Wicklow;
  - Baron Northington, of Watford in the county of Northampton;
  - Baron Hobhouse, of Hadspen in the county of Somerset;
- [14 July 1885](https://hansard.parliament.uk/lords/1885-07-14/debates/1d0d9156-3b94-4131-b824-d64fff228942/NewPeer):

  - Earl of Ormelie in the county of Caithness, and Marquess of Breadalbane;
- [27 July 1885](https://hansard.parliament.uk/lords/1885-07-27/debates/d0191911-4e18-483c-9e70-6aea09c10aa2/NewPeers):

  - Earl of Fife, [in that part of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland called Ireland];
  - Baron Esher of Esher in the county of Surrey;

Comment: By contrast, the election was 24 November to 18 December.

Comment: Re. "_Mysteriously..._": Could be errors in transcription, but it's possible he never fully took his seat (if that's the right phrase). There's no mention of him in the "New Peer(s)" section through to 1887, and the first search result for "_Iddesleigh_" or "_Northcote_" is the Lords' [27/01/1887 reaction to his recent death](https://hansard.parliament.uk/lords/1887-01-27/debates/5a31b720-0c5f-4bef-ac03-b5e69ee2c96e/TheLateLordIddesleigh), which includes "_Lord Iddesleigh was well known to many of us; but to this House as a whole he had not had the opportunity of making himself acquainted_".

Comment: @TripeHound: Wow! What an obituary. We should all be so fortunate as to be thus regarded in our passing. Thank you for that.